# Rspec with Ruby basic output String testing raises an error

Tags: ruby, string, rspec, standards, output

I've tried to write the most basic test I could with Rspec, in order to test the reception of a String on the standard output.

I've stubed the standard output exactly the same way as it's written in the RSpec Book like this :

```
require './tweetag.rb'

 module Tweetag 
  describe Tweet do
    describe "#print" do
      it "prints test" do
        output = double('output').as_null_object
        t = Tweetag::Tweet.new(output)
        t.print
        output.should_receive(:puts).with('test')
   end
  end
 end 
end
```

The Ruby code looks like this :

```
module Tweetag
  class Tweet
    def initialize(output)
      @output=output
    end

    def print
      @output.puts('test')
    end

  end
end
```

As you can see, nothing really complicated. But still, the answer I receive after running the specs is the following :

```
Failures:

  1) Tweetag::Tweet#print prints test
     Failure/Error: output.should_receive(:puts).with('test')
       (Double "output").puts("test")
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

I've tried removing the "as_null_object" and then the answer was :

```
  1) Tweetag::Tweet#print prints test
     Failure/Error: t.print
       Double "output" received unexpected message :puts with ("test")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is "how am I supposed to make the test pass ?

I've done exactly what is written in the book to pass...

Comment: Write that in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `should_receive` method has to be used before actually calling the method.

```
output = double('output').as_null_object
t = Tweetag::Tweet.new(output)
output.should_receive(:puts).with('test')
t.print
```

As a side note, your test is missing a check on the return value here. You know the print method doesn't raises any exception. But you don't check that the return value is appropriate.

```
output.should_receive(:puts).with('test').and_return('returned value')
t.print.should eql('returned value')
```

Comment: C'est fait. Désolé pour l'attente ;) Je découvre.